# User can only view own uploaded or created document

Tags: sharepoint-online

I understand that SharePoint List provide user read items created by own, others not able to read or access

How to achieve same feature under Document Library ?

I want to avoid using different view due to privacy among users.

Comment: Do you want to achieve it using view settings (users can see all the documents in "All documents" or other views without filters) or based on permissions (users can see only their documents even without filters - need more work to achieve)?

Comment: My limited understanding, user with contribute permission able to create different view, hence, not intended to do so. Can you share more based on permissions (hope it is not document by document manage access?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, you can modify the current view to add a filter to show only the files each household uploaded or created themselves.

Edit current view->Filter:Created By is equal to [Me]
[image]